# Need to download attachment in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

In my visualforce page, having a section called 'Loan Documents' below it contains attachment. Need to download those attachment.

Comment: Click on the 'view' button next to the attachment.

Comment: Thanks @stygon. But the view button show the document as new tab. Is there possible to download it. Please explain abut the possibilities in codes aswell

Comment: Let's try right click - save link as

Comment: Yes Stygon. i tried this works very well. But here i want to do it by clicking on Button - 'Download'. I am having limited experience in both visaulforce and apex.

Comment: public PageReference getfile(){   if(uploadHistoryList.size() != null){
        uploadHistory = [SELECT genesis_Account_Id__c, genesis_Application_Id__c, Loan_App_Id__c, Product_Related_Doc_Name__c, Document_URL__c,   is_Doc_Verified__c,  FROM Upload_History__c WHERE genesis_Application_Id__c =: application.Id  AND Loan_App_Id__c =: loanApplication.Loan_ID__c ];
         Attachment attachment = [SELECT Id, Body, ContentType, Name, ParentId   FROM Attachment   WHERE ParentId =: application.Id  AND Name =: docNameForAction]; return null; }

Comment: <apex:outputLink value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={! uploadHistory.Id}&oid={!$Organization.Id}">  
                     Download Now!
                     </apex:outputLink>

Comment: Getting erorrUnable to Access Page
The value of the "file" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length. Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, YOURATTACHEMENTID)}" target="_blank">Download</apex:outputLink>
```

We use global action on attachment to allows download with stay in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

try that (it works for me)

```
  <apex:outputLink value="https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/{!Attachment ID here}" target="_blank">Download</apex:outputLink>
```

change **`https://c.eu2.visual.force.com/`** by your organization link.